# Unresolved reference when I create Empty Activity in Android Studio(3.6.1)

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a New Empty Activity in Android Studio, I see the following issue every time:

[image]

This issue will resolved when I do Invalidate Caches / Restart, but having to do this each new activity is not a good solution.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Android Studio version : 3.6.1

Comment: Have you defined the activity in your manifest?!

Answer (score 0):

> In Android 3.6.1 there is lots of bug related to xml. I faced same issue.
>
> Please update it to 3.6.2

Comment: It's solved to me. Also in 3.6.1 databinding issue available means working but it's showing xml in red.

Comment: After updating was working fine ,but now facing the same issue.
`Currant android studio version is 3.6.3`